# Getting CLR object property raises Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject'

Tags: c#, com, kinect

I'm trying to get the value of a property via reflection, but end up getting the following exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
>
> Inner Exception:
> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Kinect.Interop.INuiColorCameraSettings'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00A4B392-E315-470C-90B7-F7B4C3CE00C4}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

My code looks like the following, where `src` is an istance of `Microsoft.Kinect.ColorCameraSettings`, and `propName = "Brightness"`:

```
var prop = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
if (prop != null)
{
    return prop.GetValue(src, null);
}
```

I've also tried the supposedly more COM-friendly method, but with the same issue:

```
return src.GetType().InvokeMember(propName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, src, null);
```

Most interestingly, there is nothing to suggest that `src` is a COM object:
`src.GetType().IsCOMObject` returns `false`

But it seems from the inner exception stack trace that the src object internally interacts with a COM object.

```
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at Microsoft.Kinect.Interop.INuiColorCameraSettings.GetBrightness(Double& pBrightness)
   at Microsoft.Kinect.NuiColorCameraSettings.GetBrightness()
   at Microsoft.Kinect.ColorCameraSettings.get_Brightness()
```

How can I get the value of this property via reflection at runtime?

Edit: Here is what the Threads window looks like when the exception is thrown
[image]

---

EDIT: Been meaning  to update this. Solution here is to run the code on the correct thread, which in this case is a worker from the thread pool. Simply wrapping the call with a `Task.Run()` works well. The exception (for me at least) isn't very clear about the underlying cause.

Comment: I'm pretty sure var is bound at run time. Could it be the type you are trying to get via reflection has an internal property that is set at run time?

Comment: Nope, you can safely assume that you are using COM when you talk to a Kinect, it is Microsoft's universal glue to their C++ code.  Two basic reasons.  The Kinect product was discontinued a long time ago so Lord knows where you got the interop library from, and it is incompatible like the exception says.  Or this code runs on a worker thread and the library doesn't support threading, use Debug > Windows > Threads to see that.  Do feel free to take that Kinect device out to the parking lot and run it over with your car a couple of times, the other way to end support.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your reply, and making me laugh at your last suggestion. I'm using the official Microsoft Kinect SDK v1.8 here (which is still available, btw). You're correct that there are worker threads involved here, but it's running on the main thread when the exception is thrown. You think this code needs to run on the worker thread with name "Background M-NUI Thread"??

Comment: You probably must use the object on the same thread that created it. And that thread should be STA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been meaning to update this. Solution here is to run the code on the correct thread, which in this case is a worker from the thread pool. Simply wrapping the call with a Task.Run() works well. The exception (for me at least) isn't very clear about the underlying cause.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with getting the property values of a System.__ComObject too.
Initially, the ComObject was a java object with a few properties.
The GetType() solution didn't work for me, so I searched more and found TypeDescriptor as very useful and comfortable.

According to your setup, I think it would be:

```
if(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(src).Find(propName, false) != null)
{
   propval = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(src).Find(propName, false).GetValue(src).ToString();
}
```

Hopefully, it will help someone.